# spellcheck language

Tags: windows, windows-vista, german

I am doing a Livemocha German writing lesson that has a spellcheck which must be for a different language.  How can I change it to a German spellcheck?

Answer (score 0):

A Livemocha expert reviewer answered my question for me.  She suggested I write my exercise on a word processor then change (as spelled correctly) all the words underlined as spelling errors, then write the exercise on Livemocha's writing lesson.  I did it, and it worked.  The next written exercise had no German words underlined on my side of the submission--what it did on Livemocha's side I have no idea. I don't know why it worked, but it just did. This reviewer also suggested that next time I should ask someone at Livemocha. That seems to be good advice. Dan Thompson.